# MySQL Join on Same Table using WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have a table that keeps track of pinball high scores. Tables/Columns as follows:

```
table: pinball_scores
columns: table_id (pinball table), initials, score
```

What I want to be able to do is get the high score for an individual pinball table (table_id, MAX(score)) and then compare it to a players highest score for that pinball table (table_id, initials, MAX(score)) and show the difference ( table_high_score - player_table_high_score = difference.

EDIT: Since apparently I didn't ask "right"
Given the following data:
#1
table_id: 1 (pinball table game id, ie. "Attack From Mars")
MAX(score): 810000 AS game_high_score WHERE table_id='1'
#2
table_id: 1
initials: AAA (player name)
MAX(score) WHERE table_id='1' AND initials='AAA' AS player_game_high_score
#3
table_id: 1
SUM(game_high_score - player_game_high_score) AS 'difference'

Desired output:
game_high_score | player_game_high_score | difference

I am aware this is basic SQL, and I am a beginner at SQL, which is why I'm here asking the question.

Comment: Read [ask], add some more info to your question.

Comment: What do you mean by `(pinball table)`?  what did you try to write yourself? (This is basic SQL )   Deo you have some sample data with desired output?

Comment: On a side note: The `table_id` seems to  be numeric, so why `table_id='1'` and not `table_id=1`?. (And if course, `table_id` is a weird name, I'd expect something like `game_id` or `pinball_game_id` linking to a table called `game` or `pinball_game`). Single quotes delimit string literals, don't use them for names. This means `AS 'difference'` should be `AS \`difference\`` or even better just `AS difference`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to get the maximum score per game:

```
select table_id, max(score) as high_score
from pinball_scores
group by table_id;
```

Here is how to get the maximum score per game and player:

```
select table_id, initials, max(score) as high_score
from pinball_scores
group by table_id, initials;
```

The two combined:

```
select
  table_id,
  p.initials,
  p.high_score as player_game_high_score,
  g.high_score as game_high_score,
  g.high_score - p.high_score as difference
from
(
  select table_id, max(score) as high_score
  from pinball_scores
  group by table_id
) g
join
(
  select table_id, initials, max(score) as high_score
  from pinball_scores
  group by table_id, initials;
) p using (table_id)
order by table_id, p.initials
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause to limit this to a single player of course.